# Разобрать словарь python

Tags: python, список

У меня есть код:

```
for item in enumerate(results['item']):
    track = item['name']
    print(track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

но мне нужно получить их из словаря ниже:

```
    {'device': {'id': '6890eef5ba942bfc60daa1540a0cceff5b3e1f3e', 'is_active': True, 'is_private_session': False, 'is_restricted': False, 'name': 'DESKTOP-999H6JD', 'type': 'Computer', 'volume_percent': 100}, 'shuffle_state': False, 'repeat_state': 'off', 'timestamp': 1645969204614, 'context': {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}, 'progress_ms': 5096, 'item': {'album': {'album_type': 'album', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS', 'id': '6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS', 'name': 'Убей меня, Эйс!', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 
'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 
'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/5YFUCDfdfBHfGoRuvWoKOO'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5YFUCDfdfBHfGoRuvWoKOO', 'id': '5YFUCDfdfBHfGoRuvWoKOO', 'images': [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27373e890f417e830e20689913d', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0273e890f417e830e20689913d', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485173e890f417e830e20689913d', 'width': 64}], 'name': 'МЫ 
- Тоска', 'release_date': '2020-06-19', 'release_date_precision': 'day', 'total_tracks': 12, 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:5YFUCDfdfBHfGoRuvWoKOO'}, 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS', 'id': '6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS', 'name': 'Убей меня, Эйс!', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:6a0o2otpPIVqPpeuGGOTiS'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'disc_number': 1, 'duration_ms': 176687, 'explicit': False, 'external_ids': {'isrc': 'QM6N22052522'}, 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/72ueFJnlw9yGiZWuV1oE0I'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/72ueFJnlw9yGiZWuV1oE0I', 'id': '72ueFJnlw9yGiZWuV1oE0I', 'is_local': False, 'name': 'Вальс', 'popularity': 36, 'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/2cd7f83aecbd6e6208cb81cfb2bd14c7ce6861ce?cid=4027f4db7c2c46049cb2c93abf9e1131', 'track_number': 2, 
'type': 'track', 'uri': 'spotify:track:72ueFJnlw9yGiZWuV1oE0I'}, 'currently_playing_type': 'track', 'actions': {'disallows': {'resuming': True}}, 'is_playing': True}
```

Не получается это сделать.

Comment: Снизу у вас формат json скорее всего, что вы хотите получить из него?

Comment: 'name': 'Убей меня, Эйс!' и 'name': 'Вальс'

Comment: Как вы получили эти данные? Загрузчик json: ругается!

Comment: @Александр Это не json. ТС в вопросе так и написал, что имеется словарь python. И приведенный текст это стандартное представление питоновского словаря

Comment: Данные не соответствуют формату "питоновского" словаря.

Comment: Зачем вы делаете enumerate, он же возвращает пары (tuple) с элементами и номерами, причем из массива, а не из структуры. results['item']['name'] - это название итема, т.е. Вальс, а артистов по идее может быть много, первый из них это results['item']['artists'][0]['name'] "Убей меня, Эйс!". Если нужны все arists, когда их будет много надо перебирать циклом results['item']['artists']

Comment: @Александр Как это не соответствуют. Вот я просто взял этот текст, вставил его в код программы и прекрасно напечатал то, что хочет ТС: https://ideone.com/SVQadK

Comment: Ясно, у меня просто выдавал InvalidSyntax, поэтому я предположил что это json.

Comment: @Александр Ну там один перевод каретки неуместный, видимо внутри строки встретился. А у json кавычки двойные и true/false маленькими буквами, его сразу на глаз отличить можно

Comment: Спасибо учту...

Comment: @Mike СПАСИБО! Сутки мучался над проблемой.